# Empty parameter pack expansion different to manual empty parameter pack

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, variadic-templates

It seems that GCC treats expanding an empty parameter pack `A` into another
parameter pack `B` differently than manually entering an empty parameter pack
`B`. Example:

```
void baz();
void baz(int);

template<typename... Args, typename R>
void bar(R (*)(Args...));

template<typename... Args>
void foo()
{
    bar<Args...>(baz);
}

int main()
{
    foo<>();          // Deduces baz()
    //bar<>(baz);     // Ambiguous
    foo<int>();       // Deduces baz(int)
    bar<int>(baz);    // Deduces baz(int)
    //foo<void>();    // Ambiguous
    //bar<void>(baz); // Ambiguous
}
```

Is this behaviour standard conforming? You can see a live example of the difference [here](http://ideone.com/5uG5Cp) and [here](http://ideone.com/0O3Vyh).

Comment: `f<>` doesn't force empty pack, just tells the first 0 arguments of the template argument.

Comment: @Jarod42 this is interesting and counter intuitive. Can you elaborate this in an answer?

Comment: I wonder why `template<typename... Args, typename R>` is correct. Shouldn't it be `template< typename R, typename... Args>`?

Comment: @Glapa is correct. why wouldn't it be correct?

Comment: I though that variadic parameter should be last. It seems that I learned something new about it ;)

Comment: @Glapa: The parameter after variadic should be deductible (and `R(*)(Args...)`) allow that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`f<>` doesn't force empty pack, just tells the first 0 arguments of the template argument.

Clang rejects `foo<>()` ([Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/939ee0ae79e54aa5)) as it can't decide which overload of `baz` for `bar<>(baz);`

The fact that gcc accepts it seems to be a bug.